# Unable to parse Java MIME mail message

Tags: java, email, parsing, mime-message

I'm creating java MIMEMessage object from input stream.
It is getting constructed properly without any problem.

I'm also able to fetch body and attachments.
But the problem is, when I receive some emails with some different formating, like from iPhone or from Blackberry, my parsing fails.

I'm parsing Java MIMEMessage by myself.

Here I need a standard library which can parse Java MIMEMessage and provides me body and attachments.

Can anybody suggest me any library which can cater the unexpected email formats?

Answer (score 2):

Another Java-Mail API is mime4j (http://james.apache.org/mime4j/index.html).

Comment: Its not that Javax mail is not parsing email properly, it is doing that.
But the way MimeMessage is constructed is the problem.
So I need a component after these parsers, which can strip of email body and attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason preventing you from using [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) (see the [javax.mail.internet package](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html))?